# localstorage is not working after window.location.href

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, angular

I am setting a value checked using localstorage.setitem and using window.location.href to redirect to another page. When page loads and I am trying to acess the saved value using localstorage.getitem, it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="names" onchange="submit(this)" />
 function submit(element) {
                            var names = document.getElementsByName('names');
                            var selectedList = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                                if (names[i].checked == true) {
                                    window.localStorage.setItem(names[i].checked, "checked");
                                }
                            }
                            window.location.href = "/testpage.html";
                            
                        }
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            var names = document.getElementsByName('names');
                            for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                                if (window.localStorage.getItem(names[i].checked) == "checked") {
                                    names[i].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
                                }
                            }
                        })
```

Comment: `window.location.href = "/testpage.html";` loads a new page ... the javascript following it won't run - i.e. the `$(document).ready(function () {` needs to be javascript in `testpage.html`

Comment: this submit function is callled in same page where document.ready function is called. I mean to say in same page. @Bravo

Comment: right, all that code is in a page that is unloaded when you redirect to a new page ... therefore the document ready code is no longer in the browser, and therefore won't run

Comment: let me give you a example. There is a list of checkboxes in a page, when user clicks one checkbox, its value is set to the url and page reloads. now when page reload that checkbox checked earlier has to be checked. So in submit function when a checkbox is checked, set the value checked using localstorage and when the page reloads get the checkbox status and set attribute just like how it works in amazon.com @Bravo

Comment: no example needed ... redirecting means current code disappears, wont' run, as if it never existed *just like how it works in amazon.com* - except they don't expect code from the current page to exist in the page redirected to ... you're loading a whole new page

Comment: what would be the best way to handle this problem then?

Comment: handle it in `testpage.html` as that is the page that is now loaded after the redirect - also you'llneed to understand how form submit works and probably how to prevent the default action from happening

Comment: what if they are in same page.lets say if we dont have testpage.html, and everything is happening in same page.

Comment: then you don't need to submit a form, you don't need to redirect and you don't need that document ready

Comment: Click "view source", if your JS code is present then there is a better chance it will work. One page or two.

Comment: but  how would I display checkbox checked when my url gets refreshed then,

Comment: my JS code is present in the view source

Comment: Most people use cookies and some server side code. If you are trying to do some static  site then this type of storage can work. You can observe the local storage, have you determined if your issue is on the getter or setter?

Comment: I need to use storage. @ficuscr

Comment: When setting it is working fine. I will run into problem when i change url. The requirement is if checkbox is checked I need to update url and refresh the page. After refresh all storage is reset.@ficuscr

Comment: Show the full URLs. Are you changing protocol for example? HTTP to HTTPS would cause this, or www.domain.com to domain.com.

Comment: i am using localhost@ficuscr

Comment: You are probably clobbering yourself, one of the things Bravo was alluding to. Separate the code into two files. Ask your question again and clearly show the two code snippets from each file. This is something that should be easy to reproduce. Maybe you solve the problem yourself during refactoring.

Comment: I cannot put into two files. It has to be in same files. This is where I am getting confused,

Comment: the checkboxed and displaying content based on checkbox checked has to happen in same page and files.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're on page `x.html` and you're redirecting to another page from this page using this line
`window.location.href = "/testpage.html";`
So any code written in `javascript` of `x.html` after the redirecting will not execute, because the execution context of JS now moves to `javascript` written for `testpage.html`.
With that said, the solution to your problem will be, to set the localStorage from `x.html`'s JS and when redirected to `testpage.html` the handle the getting from localStorage part there and then set the values gotten fro localStorage to the checkboxes.

Let's see example of what i've explained above.
Your `x.html` should look something like this:

```js
 function submit(element) {
      var names = document.getElementsByName('names');
      var selectedList = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
          if (names[i].checked == true) {
              window.localStorage.setItem(names[i].checked, "checked");
          }
      }
      window.location.href = "/testpage.html";
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="names" onchange="submit(this)" />
```

And javascript for `testpage.html` should look something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var names = document.getElementsByName('names');
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (window.localStorage.getItem(names[i].checked) == "checked") {
            names[i].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        }
    }
})
```